# Conver Yii2 php stdClass() Object to Object of Specific Class

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have a Array from MySql Query and What I did is convert it to object. But after convert into object Is has become object of stdClass() So I want it to be a object of Theme class.

My Cotroller Code

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    // $theme = Theme::find()->all();
    $query = "SELECT t.*,COUNT(d.id) AS total_downloads FROM `themes` AS T 
                        LEFT JOIN downloads AS D 
                        ON D.theme_id = T.id GROUP 
                        by t.id ORDER BY total_downloads DESC LIMIT 6";
        $connection=Yii::$app->db;  
        $trends = $connection->createCommand($query);
        $model = $trends->queryAll();


    return $this->render('index',[
                'model'=>$model,
            ]);
}
```

And View Code Look Like

```
<?php foreach ($model as $themes): ?>
<?php $theme = (object) $themes; ?>

<?php var_dump($theme) ?>
<div class="col-md-4">

</div>  
<?= $theme->name ?>
```

How can I covert `$model` to a object of class `Theme.php`

Comment: Count query is doing good job, Count is not a problem. I just wanted to convert this array **model** to be **Object** of _theme_ class

Comment: Could you also explain why you don't use the `Theme` class right away?

Comment: Because It is not working as i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I found a Solution here.

```
 function cast($destination, $sourceObject)
{
    if (is_string($destination)) {
        $destination = new $destination();
    }
    $sourceReflection = new ReflectionObject($sourceObject);
    $destinationReflection = new ReflectionObject($destination);
    $sourceProperties = $sourceReflection->getProperties();
    foreach ($sourceProperties as $sourceProperty) {
        $sourceProperty->setAccessible(true);
        $name = $sourceProperty->getName();
        $value = $sourceProperty->getValue($sourceObject);
        if ($destinationReflection->hasProperty($name)) {
            $propDest = $destinationReflection->getProperty($name);
            $propDest->setAccessible(true);
            $propDest->setValue($destination,$value);
        } else {
            $destination->$name = $value;
        }
    }
    return $destination;
```

and call function like this

```
    <?php 
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    $theme_obj = new \common\models\Theme();
    use common\Constant;
 ?>

 <?php foreach ($model as $themes): ?>
    <?php $theme = (object) $themes; ?>
    <?php var_dump(Constant::cast($theme_obj , $theme)) ?>
 <?php endforeach ?>
```

It works perfectly for me.